# Changing a string array depending on an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

My knowledge of coding is very new and basic, but I am writing a hobby program and need some help. I have searched for the answer to my question but sometimes I am even finding it difficult what question to ask!

What I'm currently trying to do is to name a randomly selected creature in a list accordingly depending on whether its a group or not. This is what I have so far:

```
    String[] grouptype = {"a","a group of"};
    String group = grouptype[ran.nextInt(grouptype.length)];

    if ("a".equals(group)) { 
        String[] creaturename = {"bee" , "elf" , "goblins"};
    }
    else {
      String[] creaturename = {"bees", "elves", "goblins"};
    }
```

So far this statement does not appear to work at all- I'd like the second array group to be where I pick a creature name from if group equals "a". I apologize for my poor skills but I'd appreciate help, even if its help formatting my questions as I'm sure I will have many more in the future.

Comment: Thank you I will use that in the future. In this case the problem I seem to be encountering is that I cannot change creaturename as it is using it twice. My intent was to redefine String[] creaturename depending on whether group= "a" or not.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem

The scope of createname is limited to the code block in which they are created i.e. in the `if` or `else`

```
String[] grouptype=  {"a","a group of"};
String[] creaturename = null;
String group = grouptype[ran.nextInt(grouptype.length)];

if ("a".equals(group)) { 
    creaturename = new String [] {"bee" , "elf" , "goblins"};
}
else {
   creaturename = new String [] {"bees", "elves", "goblins"};
}

// return/print? createname
```

**note**

Fixed typo.

Comment: So in other words, if I create a variable inside of an if statement it will not exist anywhere else, therefore it is not able to be used in the following else like I tried?

Comment: No you can, but you can not access it outside of the block in which it was declared.  If you were to return that variable from the block, it should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't approach this problem with the structures / concepts you have in your implementation.  How to organize code is always the question, regardless of language.

In this case your primary concept is a creature.  So I would probably create a class called Creature, which has a name property, like "Goblin" or "Bee" or "Orc".  You could have a public method on this class that returns the plural form for a group as well.

Then you could create a List or array of Creature objects, select a random one, and access either the singular or group name of that random creature as you wish.

```
    public class Creature
    {
        private String name;
        private String groupName;

        public Creature(String name, String groupName) {
            this.name = name;
            this.groupName = groupName;
        }

        public String getGroupName()
        {
            return groupName;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

And to run it:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class CreatureGenerator
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Creature goblin = new Creature("Goblin", "Goblins");
            Creature elf = new Creature("Elf", "Elves");

            ArrayList creatures = new ArrayList();
            creatures.add(goblin);
            creatures.add(elf);

            Creature randomCreature = creatures.get(new Random().nextInt(creatures.size()));
            System.out.println("A " + randomCreature.getName());
            System.out.println("A group of " + randomCreature.getGroupName());
        }
    }
```

You can see in this example some interesting questions - like "A elf" vs. "An elf".  Perhaps the creature class itself could know how to generate the full singular form of the description and the full plural form.  Perhaps even the creature class knows how many of a particular creature there are - like 1-10 or 1-6 like you might have in an RGP monster type description.

There are always many choices about how to organize code to make it clear and easy to understand and change later.

Comment: You are right I believe, I pared my program back a lot as I was finding the initial way I had organized it was causing me issues. Learning how to use classes would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `creatureName` out of the `if-else` statement. And please follow the java naming convention.

```
String[] creatureName;
if ("a".equals(group)) { 
    creatureName = new String[]{"bee", "elf", "goblins"};
}else{
    creatureName = new String[]{"bees", "elves", "goblins"};
}
```